# What's the best practice to add default function to jQuery Dialog open/close events?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to define some default behaviours for my jQuery Dialogs like the following:

```
(function($) {
        /**
         * Overriding default options
         **/
        $.ui.dialog.defaults.bgiframe = true;
        $.ui.dialog.defaults.open = function() {
            if ($('.ui-widget-overlay').length == 0) return;
            if ($.browser.msie) {
                // scrollbar fix for IE
                $('html').css('overflow-y','hidden');
                $('html').css('overflow-x','hidden');
            } else {
                // disable scrollbar for other browsers
                $('body').css('overflow','hidden');
            }
        };
        $.ui.dialog.defaults.beforeclose = function(event, ui) {
            if ($('.ui-widget-overlay').length == 0) return;
            if ($.browser.msie) {
                // scrollbar fix for IE
                $('html').css('overflow-y','auto');
                $('html').css('overflow-x','auto');
            } else {
                // disable scrollbar for other browsers
                $('body').css('overflow','auto');
            }
        };
})(jQuery);
```

The above works when I have no custom open/beforeclose function specified when the dialog is created. So I'm wondering what is the best practice to add these functionality into all my dialogs, while preserving the ability to specify open/beforeclose functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I think I figured this out. Following is the least intrusive way of extending jQuery UI functions by attaching the events in _init function.

```
(function($) {
        /**
         * Overriding default options
         **/
        $.ui.dialog.defaults.bgiframe = true;

        var _init = $.ui.dialog.prototype._init;
        $.ui.dialog.prototype._init = function() {
            _init.apply(this, arguments);
            // only applying these function for modal dialog
            if (this.options.modal) {
                this.uiDialog.bind('dialogopen.ui-dialog', function() {
                    if ($.browser.msie) {
                        // scrollbar fix for IE
                        $('html').css('overflow-y','hidden');
                        $('html').css('overflow-x','hidden');
                    } else {
                        // disable scrollbar for other browsers
                        $('body').css('overflow','hidden');
                    }
                }).bind('dialogbeforeclose.ui-dialog', function() {
                    if ($.browser.msie) {
                        // scrollbar fix for IE
                        $('html').css('overflow-y','auto');
                        $('html').css('overflow-x','auto');
                    } else {
                        // disable scrollbar for other browsers
                        $('body').css('overflow','auto');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're overriding defaults here. **More likely than not**, you **don't** want to be doing that. You're reaching in and tinkering with how the plugin itself was written, essentially. The way that you should be attaching these kinds of behaviors is by passing it into the config when you initialize your jQueryUI dialog:

```
$('some selector').dialog({
    bgiframe: true,
    open: function() { /* your code */ },
    beforeclose: function(event, ui) { /* your code */ }
});
```

Even more correctly, what you should be doing to conform to what the API specifies is initializing the dialog as normal, and then subsequently binding to its events:

```
var $dialog = $('some selector');
$dialog.dialog({ /* your config */ });
$dialog.bind('dialogopen', function() { /* your code */ });
$dialog.bind('dialogbeforeclose', function(event, ui) { /* your code */ });
```

It seems like a deeper problem is that you're not used to jQuery just yet. I think if you spend a little time reading some established jQuery code on GitHub, you'll get the hang of it pretty quickly.

Also, as a side note, I would be cautious about applying CSS properties directly to `body` and `html` on dialog load; if these things aren't things that can go in your CSS to begin with, they're not going to be any safer to do when someone interacts with the application. Try to select something more specific, or simply apply these things with conditional CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I do agree that I need to know more about how this can be done properly. However, I can't seem to find a way to properly "extend" the default behaviour/functions for all future created dialog for example. The example you given outlined on how to apply these settings "after" the dialog has been constructed, but I would like to make these function available by default for all dialogs on my website. Do you mind giving me some pointer on how that can be properly done?

Comment: Sorry had to make 2 comments. As for the CSS, I'm not quite sure how this can be done with just CSS since I would only disable the scroll bars when it is a modal dialog. I'm definitely interested in knowing the proper way of implementing that as well!

Comment: Would simply making the dialog position fixed be a solution? Then it'll hover with the page even if the user scrolls.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option. Which is why I'm interested in the technique for properly override/extend jquery ui default functions.

Answer (score 0):

This is now better achieved by listening to events instead of modifying the dialog prototype. The following code disables document scrollbars when a modal dialog is open. It re-enables them when all modal dialogs are closed (remember there can be more than one!).

```
$(document)
  .on('dialogopen', function(e) {
    var $el = $(e.target);
    // Modal dialogs should disable scrollbars
    if ($el.dialog('option', 'modal')) {
      $el.addClass('modal-dialog');
      $('body').css({overflow: 'hidden'});
    }
  })
  .on('dialogclose', function(e) {
    // Restore scrollbars when closing modal
    if ($('.ui-dialog .modal-dialog:visible').not(e.target).length < 1) {
      $('body').css({overflow: ''});
    }
  });
```